# Why is this Kotlin extension failing Android Studio Lint checks?

Tags: android, kotlin

Within Android development, there is often a time in which a block of code needs to be executed if and only if the device's SDK is greater than or equal to a minimum version.

To avoid the often ugly and repetitive nature of this code, I created the following extension.

```
inline fun <T> runWithMinSdk (minVersion: Int, func: () -> T) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= minVersion) { func() }
}
```

Nothing too fancy, and seems to do the trick on paper.

*However*, when I use this code as such:

```
fun myFun {
    runWithMinSdk(Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        exampleMethodThatRequiresOreo()
    }
}
```

Android Studio throws a hissy fit and it fails the Lint checks, asking to either suppress 'NewApi' warnings within `myFun()` or wrapping the `runWithMinSdk` block with `if android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ... etc`

Is there a better way to achieve this functionality, make it pass the Lint checks or is none of this possible using extensions?

Answer (score 1):

The [androidX annotation library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/annotation) provides a nice solution for this:

```
@ChecksSdkIntAtLeast(parameter = 0)
inline fun <T> runWithMinSdk(minVersion: Int, func: () -> T) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= minVersion) { func() }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [this discussion in the Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/minimum-api-level-annotations/2340) it seems like doing something like this isn't possible, because Lint can only look at the current function for annotations. For instance if you do

```
val func = @TargetApi(26) { exampleMethodThatRequiresOreo() }
runWithMinSdk(Build.VERSION_CODES.0, func)
```

you won't get the warning, but that also kinda defeats the purpose of this extension function. The OP in the discussion above mentions taking the feature request to Anko, but I couldn't find an associated issue there.